# compare the first state to the last state reactjs

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I am trying to make an edit page. I am update the state for any changes made. I want to compare the initial state with the last state on the last save. but I can not control the first state.

```
export default class extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.changeDetails = this.changeDetails.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            driver: this.props.driver
        }
    }

    changeDetails = value => {
        this.setState({
            driver:value
        })
    }

    onRegister = () => {
        //I want to make a comparison here.

    }


    render() { 
        const {driver} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
               <EditView driver={driver} changeDetails={this.changeDetails}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**EditView.js**

```
 export default class extends Component {
      render() {
        const { driver} = this.props;

        const changeDetails = event => {
            driver['fname] = event.target.value;
            this.props.changeDetails(driver);
          };

        return (
          <div>
            <Input
                value={driver.fname}
                onChange={event => changeDetails(event)}
                />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to compare why don't you hold two separate state values? Or even better if your "driver" data won't change here, why don't you hold just one state and compare it to your "driver" prop?

Comment: (oldDriver = this.props.driver  and newDriver = this.props.driver ) I do this, but when I update the newDriver, the oldDriver also changes

Comment: Why do you set newDriver to your props value? You are getting driver prop somewhere else right? So, just hold a state for the new info via onChange then compare it to your prop (original driver data).

Comment: should I do the comparison in a parent component? I passed the driver data

Comment: Let me understand your logic better. Here (first component) gets a prop named driver. You are rendering EditView component and getting a value from there via onChange handler. Can't you set this value in the state and compare it the original driver prop in the first Component?

Comment: that's the problem anyway. I can not keep the original driver data. how do you do it?what am I doing wrong logically?

Comment: Your original data should not be changed if the logic is right. It is a prop and you are not changing it here and you should not. I'm not sure this is what you want but here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/x24xrknm4

Comment: It also updates the data from props, me. So both are the same. i dont understand :/

Comment: If you are referencing your code as it is, this is because you are setting a state named driver via prop (again driver) and changing this state again. Actually, the prop itself is not changing in the original place. If you are not referencing the code here it will be good to show whole code with every components if possible.

Comment: By the way, here, do not set a state with your driver prop. Name a new state and change it, then compare those as I did in my example.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/v01vxxmyxy There is nothing else I do. I fetch the data and send it to the child component.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9mzvmlm45 As you can see this fork is working without actions and state part from redux. Actually, this is the same logic with my previous example. The difference is one extra component. Old, the original driver data never changes. I can not test your code since we need other parts like redux stuff (store,actions,reducers etc). This is why I used a static state in MainComponent. You are getting your driver data from global state and passing that to your component. Original data should not be changed. If it changes that means something goes wrong and weird.

Comment: I partially found the problem. Now there is no problem using single string here. but the driver is an object. `const handleChange = event => {
  driver['fname'] = event.target.value;
    this.props.changeDetails(driver);
};`   the problem may be here.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/4q5zqp3r89 @devserkan can you control it ?

Comment: You are getting into problem since mutating the driver itself completely. You can do it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xjn72x45n By the way, note that I'm using defaultValue instead of value here.

Comment: interesting, thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) I'm dropping a concise answer now, if you accept it then we can check one more question as "answered" on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate driver itself directly. Use something like this:

```
const changeDetails = event =>
    this.props.changeDetails( { ...driver, fname: event.target.value } );
```